# Celery connection broker lost makes CPU usage go to 100%

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, amqp, django-celery

We've been getting strange issues with Celery when the MainProcess it loses connection to the broker. Celery generates the error below and then starts using 100% CPU. The workers will still continue to work fine tho. I can see in that RabbitMQ thinks that the connection is timing out. We've been getting these error frequently after updating to celery 3.

I have a feeling it has something to do with the non-blocking message consuming but I'm not really progressing in understanding the code.

Is there any way to detect these earlier or prevent celery from using 100% CPU?

- Celery: 3.0.4
- AMQP: 1.0.10
- RabbitMQ: 2.8.4

The timestamp are 2 hours apart because RabbitMQ reports GMT and celery localtime.

**Celery Error**

```
[2013-05-09 18:20:20,204: ERROR/MainProcess] Consumer: Connection to broker lost. Trying to re-establish the connection...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 369, in start
    self.consume_messages()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 450, in consume_messages
    readers[fileno](fileno, event)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 290, in drain_nowait
    self.drain_events(timeout=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 279, in drain_events
    return self.transport.drain_events(self.connection, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 91, in drain_events
    return connection.drain_events(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 266, in drain_events
    chanmap, None, timeout=timeout,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 328, in _wait_multiple
    channel, method_sig, args, content = read_timeout(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 299, in read_timeout
    return self.method_reader.read_method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/method_framing.py", line 187, in read_method
    raise m
IOError: Socket closed
```

**RabbitMQ error**

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 9-May-2013::16:20:20 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.1813.0> (192.168.201.104:12809 -> 192.168.201.104:5672):
{timeout,running}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I turned broker hearbeats off which seems to have fixed to problem. However, I'm not quite certain as I don't have a way of reproducing the bug.

Comment: Worked for me using SQS broker. Thanks!